Digit Frequency Program
Given a string s consisting of alphabets and digits, find the frequency of each digit in the given string.
I have tried it and my code is given below. Please explain why it's not working.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
    int main() {
    char str[100];
    fgets(str,1000,stdin);
    int n;
    n=strlen(str);
    int sum[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(isdigit(str[i])){
            sum[str[i]]=sum[str[i]]+1;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d ",sum[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}


What is your input? What is the expected and actual output? char str[100]; and fgets(str,1000,stdin); don't match.

What happens when you build the program? What happens when you run it? For some specified input, what is your expected and actual output?

The size in the call to fgets() is ten times larger than the size of the BBC variable.  As long as you don't enter more than 98 characters in the line of input, you won't have problems, but using sizeof(str) would avoid problems.

Keep in mind that a digit in a string doesn't have a value of 0-9, it is the ascii value of '0' to '9'. You need to subtract '0' to map the value into the 0-9 range.

What is the ASCII code for ’0’?  How big is your array of counts?  Convert the letter to a number 0..9 before indexing into the array.  C has operators += and ++.

input=a11472o5t6        my output=0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0           expected output=0 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0

Change your accumulation line to
        sum[str[i]-'0']++;

and it will probably do what you want (although you didn't explain exactly what it wasn't doing in the first place).
Note that str[i] is a char and even if it happened to represent an integer its corresponding value in the collating sequence wouldn't be that value.
The digits '0', '1', '2' etc. do come in sequential order, so forming str[i]-'0' will pick off the integer corresponding to a character.

yes..it got solved

But it's not getting solved for all the inputs....like if input is b3n47b5xf13qlx233rg4u2c949i623e34nt5661se06b675utbpy258wz633855846l761d61x340h1vn19w191sj18v2u333556bh6m5uc4u050am05p961dhmpu6iq4667zg9.......then the test case is not getting solved by this code

Your array isn't big enough for that. I'd use C++ and std::string instead.

Okay..sure,I will try

For starters using magic numbers like that
char str[100];
         ^^^
fgets(str,1000,stdin);
          ^^^^

usually leads to bugs in programs. Instead use named constants or the sizeof operator. At least you could write
char str[100];
fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

Using the function strlen
int n;
n=strlen(str);

is redundant. And moreover the function has return type size_t.
The array sum should have an unsigned integer type of its elements. And there is no need to specify explicitly ten initializers of zeroes. It is enough to initialize its single element. In this case all other elements will be implicitly zero initialized. For example
unsigned int sum[10] = { 0 };

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard

In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
one greater than the value of the previous.

So to get an integer value from a character that represents a digit you can just subtract the character '0'.
Without using the function strlen this for loop
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(isdigit(str[i])){
        sum[str[i]]=sum[str[i]]+1;
    }
}

can be rewritten the following way
for ( const char *p = str; *p != '\0'; ++p )
{
    if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
    {
        ++sum[*p - '0'];
    }
}

You should declare all variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

The issue in your code lies in this line
sum[str[i]]=sum[str[i]]+1;
In this line, str[i] is a character representing a digit, but you're using it directly as an index for the sum array. This would work if the character '0' to '9' were contiguous and started from 0, but that's not the case in ASCII or any other character encoding scheme. In ASCII, for example, the character '0' has a decimal value of 48, '1' has a value of 49, and so on..
try this code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    int n = strlen(str);
    int sum[10] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            int digit = str[i] - '0'; // Convert character to integer
            sum[digit]++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", sum[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

keep coding

Okay..got the solution

"This would work if the character '0' to '9' were contiguous and started from 0, but that's not the case in ASCII or any other character encoding scheme." It is guaranteed by ISO C that '0' to '9' have contiguous values, but it says nothing of what values they hold.
